# Is it possible to synchronize an automatic layout transition with a swapchain image acquisition via pWaitDstStageMask=TOP_OF_PIPE?

Tags: vulkan

It is necessary to synchronize automatic layout transitions performed by render passes with the acquisition of a swapchain image via the semaphore provided in vkAcquireNextImageKHR. [Vulkan Tutorial states](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation#page_Subpass-dependencies), "We could change the waitStages for the imageAvailableSemaphore to VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT to ensure that the render passes don't begin until the image is available" (Context: `waitStages` is an array of `VkPipelineStageFlags` supplied as `pWaitDstStageMask` to the `VkSubmitInfo` for the queue submission which performs the render pass and, consequently, the automatic layout transition). It then opts for an alternative (common) solution, which is to use an external subpass dependency instead.

In fact, I've *only* ever seen such synchronization done with a subpass dependency; I've never seen anyone actually do it by setting `pWaitDstStageMask=TOP_OF_PIPE` for the `VkSubmitInfo` corresponding to the queue submission which performs the automatic layout transition, and I'm not certain why this would even work. The specs provide [certain guarantees](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#renderpass-layout-transitions) about automatic layout transitions being synchronized with subpass dependencies, so I understand why they would work, but in order to do this sort of synchronization by waiting on a semaphore in a `VkSubmitInfo`, it is first necessary that image layout transitions even *have* pipeline stages to begin with. I am not aware of any pipeline stages which image layout transitions go through; I believed them to be entirely atomic operations which occur in between source-available operations and destination-visible operations in a memory dependency (e.g. subpass dependency, memory barrier, etc.), as described by the specs.

Do automatic image layout transitions go through pipeline stages? If so, which stages do they go through (perhaps I'm missing something in the specs)? If not, how could setting `pWaitDstStageMask=TOP_OF_PIPE` in a `VkSubmitInfo` waiting on the image acquisition semaphore have any synchronization effect on the automatic image layout transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding what the tutorial is saying.

Layout transitions do not happen within a pipeline stage. They, like all aspects of an execution dependency, happen *between* pipeline stages. A dependency states that, after the source stage completes but before the destination stage begins, the dependency's operations will happen.

So if the destination stage of an incoming external subpass dependency is the top of the pipe, then it is saying that the layout transition as part of the dependency will happen before the execution of any pipeline stages in the target subpass.

Remember that the default external subpass dependency for each attachment has the top of the pipe as its source scope. If the semaphore wait dependency's destination stage is the top of the pipe, then the source scope of the external subpass dependency is in the destination scope of the semaphore wait. And therefore, the external subpass dependency happens-after the semaphore wait dependency.

And, as previously stated, layout transitions happen between the source scope and the destination scope. So until the source scope, and *everything* it depends on, finishes execution, the layout transition will not happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This all perfectly matches my understanding (perhaps I poorly conveyed my understanding), but that is not what the tutorial states. It is not suggesting setting the destination stage of an incoming external subpass dependency to TOP_OF_PIPE. It is suggesting setting the `pWaitDstStageMask` for the `VkSubmitInfo` containing the rendering commands to TOP_OF_PIPE. It phrases it as "We could change the waitStages for the imageAvailableSemaphore to VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT", where `waitStages` is the stages array supplied to `pWaitDstStageMask` in the `VkSubmitInfo`.

Comment: I've edited my question to (hopefully) clarify some things

Comment: @Nerdizzle: I don't see what that changes. A dependency works the same way whether it's a subpass external dependency, a pipeline barrier, or a semaphore wait dependency.

Comment: Right, but I thought that automatic layout transitions are always defined by subpass dependencies (and if you don't define one, then an implicit one will be defined for the first subpass which uses the attachment). They will then always happen between the src and dst scopes of the subpass dependency. The implicit subpass dependency does not synchronize with the PE's read / the image acquisition semaphore. So if you use an implicit subpass dependency, then the layout transition could happen before or after TOP_OF_PIPE for any command in the submission, right?

Comment: @Nerdizzle: I'm not sure what you're talking about anymore. Layout transitions work the same way whether manual or "automatic" (note that this is just a different way of specifying a manual transition). They happen between the source and destination stages of the scopes involved in the dependency (whether subpass or other). So where is the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time explaining my confusion in 600 characters. Can you point me to a place in the Vulkan spec which suggests that an automatic image layout transition can be specified with a semaphore?

Comment: @Nerdizzle: That's not what the tutorial is saying, so I don't know why you would need such a pointer. And no, the specification doesn't say that either.

Comment: Then perhaps I'm just misunderstanding your answer. The tutorial is saying that it should be possible to not define any subpass dependencies (meaning using only the implicitly defined one) and then use pWaitDstStageMask to ensure that the image layout is not transitioned before the image acquisition semaphore is signaled. I'm having a hard time seeing how this would work

Comment: Would you perhaps be available for a quick Stack Overflow chat? Here's a room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226449/automatic-image-layout-transitions-confusion

Comment: @Nerdizzle: I've added some paragraphs to my answer.

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks a ton!